# Loop every nth item and fill the blanks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build an HTML table string for every 10 items in a Javascript array, and if there are less than 10 items in the last iteration I want to fill it with empty rows.

How do I achieve this?

```
var array_of_items; //array of items

//make a html table string every 10 items
var table = '<table>';
table += '<tr><td>' + item1 + '</td></tr>';
table += '<tr><td>' + item2 + '</td></tr>';
.
.
.
table += '<tr><td>' + item10 + '</td></tr>';
table += '</table>';

//make second table
table = '<table>';
table += '<tr><td>' + item11 + '</td></tr>';
table += '<tr><td>' + item12 + '</td></tr>'; //array ends here
table += '<tr><td></td></tr>';
.
.
.
table += '<tr><td></td></tr>';
table += '</table>';

$('#table_div').html(table);
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [short, self-contained, example](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = '';
var numTables = Math.ceil(array_of_items.length / 10); //determine how many tables

for (var i=0;i<numTables;i++){
  table +='<table>';
  for (var j=0;j<10;j++){
    (array_of_items[i*10+j] ? table +='<tr><td>' + array_of_items[i*10+j] + '</td></tr>' : table +='<tr><td></td></tr>');
  }
  table +='</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ln = items.length;
var lnten = ln + 10 - ln%10;

var container = $('#table_div');
for (var j = 0; j < lnten; j++) {
    var tbl;
    if (j % 10 == 0)
        tbl = $('<table/>');
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    var td = $('<td/>');
    if (j < ln)
        td.text(items[j]);
    tr.append(td);
    tbl.append(tr);
    if (j % 10 == 0)
        container.append(tbl);
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/1j6m5c3s/2/)

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for this

```
for (var i = 0; i < array_of_items.length; i+=10) {
  var table = '<table>';
  for (var j = i; j < i+10; ++j) {
    if (array_of_items[j] === 'undefined') {
      table += '<tr><td></td></tr>';
    }
    else table += '<tr><td>' + array_of_items[j] + '</td></tr>';
  }
  table += '</table>';
}
```

Comment: conditional operator is backwards, can't print it if it's undefined